# Find and Replace in Excel with 2 excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel file with list of Actor names, which can be repeated, and I have another file which contains Actor names and their corresponding values and do not contain any duplicates.
So I want to replace the actor's names in first file with the values in the second file. Is there any way to do it?
Please Help.

Comment: First copy the sheet from the second file to the first one and then use the vlookup function which will help you to assign the needed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't do a straight *replacement*, you can certainly pull the corresponding values in from the other file with a simple `VLookup` formula.

Assuming your Actor names in the target sheet are in column A.

Assuming your Actor names in the source sheet are in column A, and corresponding values are in column B. Assuming there are around 100 rows of data. Assuming your source sheet is Sheet1.

Your formula would look something like:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\<Your Path Here>\[<File Name Here>]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$100,2,FALSE)`

This formula will pull the corresponding value for each Actor from the source file into the target. You'll end up with a column of Actor names and a column of corresponding values. You could then use Copy/Paste Special | Values to paste the results of the formula over the Actor names.

Also, if you have both files open at the same time, you won't need the full path in your formula - just the file name and sheet name would work.

Comment: Should the actor names be in sorted order?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(K2,'[countriesnew.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$2075,2,FALSE)    I did this, and there is an error of circular referencing.           countriesnew.xlsx : source file     K2 is the cell of target file which contains the actor name, and has to be replaced with value.

Comment: As long as you're using FALSE at the end, they don't need to be sorted, as it's looking for an exact match. And NP! Don't forget to upvote and accept if it worked :)